# SASS Mixin Syntax for '$' Prefix

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm working on a simple mixin to use in conjunction with Grunt Spritesmith. Here is what I've written so far...

```
@mixin svg($svg, $height, $width) {
    background-image:url(../../images/svg/#{$svg}.svg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:$height + px;
    width:$width + px;
    .no-svg & {
        @include sprite($#{$png});
    }
}
```

And I would use it like this...

```
@include svg("logo", 50, 100);
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm passing in just the name of the image (in this case just 'logo') to use in the background-image url, but then I need to prefix the @include sprite mixin with a dollar like so...

```
@include sprite($logo);
```

So all I need to know really is how I would format this line in Sass so that it spits out the passed in $svg variable with a $ prefixing it. This is the line which needs tweaking @include sprite($#{$png}); Thanks.

Comment: It's a shame that this can't be done, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, why don't you just apply `@include sprite(#{$svg})`

```
@mixin svg($svg, $height, $width) {
    background-image:url(../../images/svg/#{$svg}.svg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:$height + px;
    width:$width + px;
    .no-svg & {
        @include sprite(#{$svg});
    }
}

@mixin sprite($value) {
  background-image:url(../../images/png/#{$value}.png);
  ...
}

div {
  @include svg("logo", 50, 100);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
div {
  background-image: url(../../images/svg/logo.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

.no-svg div {
  background-image: url(../../images/png/logo.png);
  ...

}
```

An example : http://sassmeister.com/gist/cdccd858780acbf2d144

Comment: Because I'm using Grunt Spritesmith (https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith) which generates a mixin for using png's as a sprite rather than requesting the individual .png

Comment: @GuerillaRadio my bad I did't see that